# What's the best way to pass a message from an action controller to another action controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently using MVC5.

Imagine the scenario where one controller ActionA does its work and the redirects to another controller ActionB but also wants this second method to display a message on its related view.

If Controller ActionA sets the ViewBag.Message and then calls RedirectToAction, when ActionB starts, the value of that Message is gone.

What's the best way to pass a message from one action controller to another, without using Session ??

Comment: All answer are great. Also you could use a global variable that both controller have access to, and it's being set by the value you have in the ViewBag, if you don't want to use Session.

Comment: But then what if that value is changed by another user context while I'm using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say no session, but [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) can be a good place depending on what you're passing. It's essentially `Session` except that the item will be removed from `Session` once you've accessed it. `TempData` actually uses session by default unless you write your own provider.

Passing it as an option in the query string, or passing it as a parameter in the routing (similar to what AJ says)

Other than that you've got the standard run of the mill options that are provided in ASP.NET. [`HttpContext.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or maybe [`HttpContext.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But both of those are shared across the entire application domain so management can get tricky.

Remember, web is supposed to be stateless. So if it's really important for that message to get there, you probably want to put it in the URL somehow (query string or routing), or use a database.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

**Action A:**

```
TempData["Message"] = "Hi";
```

**Action B:**

```
var message = TempData["Message"];
```

Once you call the getter in Action B, the information will be automatically removed from memory.

[This article](http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications) is a really good explanation of the various persistence techniques available in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: OP said "without using session". TempData by default uses session as it's backend.

Comment: I inferred he meant without using the actual `Session` property. I assume he would have included TempData in there had he known about it.

Comment: If the Session is automatically handled then I guess it's ok. I assume this will take really milliseconds so not much memory usage on the server.

Comment: Keep in mind though, depending on your requirements, if the user presses "refresh" when they arrive at `ActionB` they will no longer receive the `message` because it will have disappeared from temp data. In this case AJ/@StevenV's answers are more appropriate.

Comment: I'm trying to send the notification message to be displayed on the view. If they click refresh, i guess it would ok to not show it again.

Answer (score 3):

I would put an optional argument on the method signature for ActionB, for example:

```
public ActionResult ActionB(string message = "")
```

Note that optional parameters need to be last in your parameters list.

Comment: Wouldn't that (by default routing rules) allow me to call something like `/Controller/ActionB?message=Blah`

Comment: Yes, you certainly could do that.  Without more context on what kind of app this is I chose what I find to be the simplest method.  Preventing that wouldn't be too difficult using membership or POST attributes, of course, but if it's a major concern I would definitely use TempData.

Comment: Agreed. I can't see anything *wrong* with this (by default writes are usually HTML encoded anyway), just thought I'd highlight this.